# Difference between these two commands (w & w/out "") and why?

Tags: linux, centos, find

In linux, I have a file named **test2** in my directory which I created using the touch command.

When I run the command

```
find . –name “*test*” -ls
```

It doesn't give me an error, but when I run

```
find . –name *test* -ls
```

It gave me an error

> find: paths must precede expression: test2
>   Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

`*test*` gets [glob expanded by your shell](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) (into more than one token).

Whereas no glob expansion happens in `"*test*"` because the surrounding `"` symbols prevent globbing.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is intercepting `*test*` and looking for files and directories in the current directory that match that expression, *before* it passes the expanded list to `find`. `find` expects only a single string in that spot, whereas the expanded list may be 0 or many strings.

With quotes, the shell ignores the asterisks and passes the raw string `*test*` to `find`, which then uses those asterisks as wildcards as you'd expect.